# regexp django template tag from docx xml

Tags: regex, django

I can not write a regexp for the following text:

```
<a>{<b>%<b/><vvv>asdasdasdasd<vvv/><c>%<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>%<b/><c>%<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/>
<a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>%<b/><c>%<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>{<b/><c>}<c/>}<a/><a>{<b>%<b/><c>%<c/>}<a/>{% load pytils_dt %}
{{today|ru_strftime:"%d %B %Y"}}
{{reprseller.warrant.issue_dt|date:"d.m.Y"}}
```

Necessary to allocate blocks {% text %} and {{text}}.
From:

```
<a> {<b>% <b/> ​​<vvv> asdasdasdasd <vvv/> <c>% <c/>} <a/> <a> {<b> {<b/> <c>} <c />} </ a>
```

be the result of:

```
{<b>% <b/> ​​<vvv> asdasdasdasd <vvv/> <c>% <c/>} and
{<b> {<b/> <c>} <c/>}
```

is also.

my regexp: `{[^}|^%]*?[}|%][^}]*?}`

help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{[^{%]*({[^}]+?}|%[^%]+?%)[^}%]*}` try this.

Comment: from:
<a> {<b>% <b/> ​​<vvv> asdasdasdasd <vvv/> <c>% <c/>} <a/> <a> {<b> {<b/> <c>} <c />} </ a>
be the result of:
{<b>% <b/> ​​<vvv> asdasdasdasd <vvv/> <c>% <c/>} and
{<b> {<b/> <c>} <c/>} is also

Comment: then from the result, I'll take all html tags